# Scrollable Div, find the title of the value in the middle

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

We have built an iPhone style date picker. It is functional at the moment in everything except IE. What I do not know how to do is find the tittle attribute of which ever value is in the centre.

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XHPYF/1/

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way - http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/XHPYF/7/

1. You can set in your HTML the initial value using `class='selected'`
2. Then use jQuery to determine the `top` offset value for the current selected element and save it to a variable for step 3
3. Use the `onScrollEnd` event (in your iScroll plugin) to track changes by:
   1) Clearing the current element marked as `selected`
   2) Iterating the list items to determine where the `top` offset is equal to the initially selected item and mark it as the `selected` item

---

**UPDATE** (the original solution works in Webkit browsers but Firefox works a bit different):

you'll need to parse the data from either

```
$('#minwheel .slotinner').css("-moz-transform")
// result: "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0px, -32px)"
```

or

```
$('#minwheel .slotinner').attr("style")
// result: "... -moz-transform: translate(0px, -32px) scale(1);"
```

In both cases the `-32px` would need to be parsed out and used to determine the selected list item.

Here's a solution for Firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/XHPYF/13/

---

now you just need to figure out how to make it work in IE :)

---

this is definitely an experimental user control, browser updates could potentially break it and useragent detection for determining which way to get the selected item is a pretty big no-no in general.  Still, the iPhone look and functionality is fun and cool.

Comment: Well done indeed. This was giving me headaches most of yesterday, however there is still one incompatible browser. It appears Firefox has a positioning / offset error. It does not calculate the offset / position correctly and the element maintains the first value all the way through. I spend hours trying to fix this yesterday to no avail. Any ideas?